# Adding input Parameter of class to Services.Configure<> in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to customize `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>()` method. I want to pass an instance or type of a class that `IdentityOptions` in configure in it. I don't want to use inline `Action<>` for configure. can you help me?

Comment: Could you provide code samples you are working with currently?

Comment: You could create a factory for that action. Pass whatever arguments you need and produce action that configures IdentityOptions.